# Circle select modal in addon?

Tags: python, scripting

I want to add "C" release circle select to my hotkeys and keep it in a portable file/addon. This seems to work when I run the script in blender, but the modal doesn't work when I start up blender.

```
bpy
import os


def Keymap():

    wm = bpy.context.window_manager
    kc = wm.keyconfigs.addon


    km = kc.keymaps.new('3D View', space_type='VIEW_3D', region_type='WINDOW', modal=False)
    kmi = km.keymap_items.new("view3d.select_circle", "C", "PRESS").properties.radius=1

    km = kc.keymaps.new(name='View3D Gesture Circle', space_type='VIEW_3D', region_type='WINDOW', modal=True)
    kmi = km.keymap_items.new_modal('CANCEL', 'C', 'RELEASE', any=True)    

def register():
    Keymap()

def unregister():
    Keymap()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Script below, named "km.py" and registered, works as expected for me on blender 2.8. It circle selects with set radius on <kbd>C</kbd> pressed and finishes on release.

Assumed the missing `import bpy` in question script was a copy paste error, but it may be your issue.  Always check the system console for errors.

Script:

```
import bpy

def custom_keymaps():
    wm = bpy.context.window_manager
    kc = wm.keyconfigs.addon

    km = kc.keymaps.new('3D View', space_type='VIEW_3D', region_type='WINDOW', modal=False)
    kmi = km.keymap_items.new("view3d.select_circle", "C", "PRESS")
    kmi.properties.radius = 10

    km = kc.keymaps.new(name='View3D Gesture Circle', space_type='VIEW_3D', region_type='WINDOW', modal=True)
    kmi = km.keymap_items.new_modal('CANCEL', 'C', 'RELEASE', any=True)    

custom_keymaps()
```

Only aesthetic changes re setting `kmi` after creating a new item.  (*otherwise `kmi` is set to the radius which is a little misleading*) and calling the method directly rather than via register method. Script in question also works as expected with the import and calling `register()` at level 0.

[image]
*Given a py extension and register checked*

[How to auto-run a simple script?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39249/how-to-auto-run-a-simple-script)

If you are executing this  in a registered script (sane text block name with  .py extension and the register script checkbox ticked on text editor header) then same as answer here https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/134416/15543 also applies.

`__name__` will be the sane textblock name without the python extension. When imported on register. Prob simpler to put `register()` as the last line of script in this case.

Currently your `unregister` method is also registering, however loading script this way will probably not trigger any unregisster activity.

You can import these into the python console. Let's imagine your script is called "foo.py" in the text editor then

```
import foo
foo.register()
```

will register it similarly to an addon. Later you can call

```
foo.unregister()
```

to unregister while seeing any errors printed into the python console.

PS if this is the case could possibly mark this q as a dupe.

Comment: So, I removed the whole `if _name_ == "_main_"` bit and just left the register. It doesn't really solve the problem with having the circle select modals change. Currently if I just drop this script into startup, I can change most hotkeys, but it doesn't change the view_3d gesture circle mapping. If I run it from blender's text editor it does.

Comment: See edit.  Tested  on 2.8 When test file is loaded it changes both the radius  and cancels when released as expected.

Comment: Thank you for your patience and input, I greatly appreciate the help. It works in editor as expected, but doesn't work when I copy it to my startup directory and restart blender. Blender will recognize the new keymap, but it will not recognize the new modal.

Comment: I am suggesting you add the script to your blend file register it as shown and save. Then whenever you open or load that blend it (for me on 2.8) works as expected. It can be added to default startup blend. If in startup folder  use the register method, as like for addons it gets called automatically.  However the order might count in this case. Addons and startup scriipts are called during a restricted context state. any prints in them will show up first (or early) after blender starts. A registered script gets run last.

Comment: Oh, I see. I was trying to have a portable hotkey file to share between work and home, but I suppose registering it will have to do. Thank you very much for your answer.